# Angular/Leaflet/OpenStreetMap - clicking on pin for pop-up throws error about an already defined service variable, doesn't display binded pop-up

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet, popup

The error appears in the browser, when I click on any pin. No pop-up is displayed, nothing happens, just the error in the console.

[image]

Below you will find the component that displays the map and the pins and it should display the pop-up. The service is injected in the constructor.

The same service variable is successfully used when populating the map with pins.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import { PowerPlantService } from 'src/app/services/power-plant.service';
import { PowerPlant } from 'src/app/models/power-plant.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    //coordinates for Brasov
  private latitude: number = 45.6427;
  private longitude: number = 25.5887;
  
  marker!: CustomPinMarker ;
  
  private map!: L.Map;
  private centroid: L.LatLngExpression = [this.latitude, this.longitude];
  powerPlantList!: PowerPlant[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initMap();
  }
  
  constructor(private powerPlantService: PowerPlantService) {

  }

  private initMap(): void {
    this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: this.centroid,
      zoom: 2.8
    });

    const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
    {
      minZoom: 2.8,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    });

    tiles.addTo(this.map);
  
     /*
    the get request made through the HttpClient call will generate an Observable type to which we have to subscribe and unsubscribe at the end.
    */

    this.powerPlantService.getAll().subscribe(powerPlantArrayFromGet => {
      console.log(powerPlantArrayFromGet);
      this.powerPlantList = powerPlantArrayFromGet;
      this.powerPlantList.forEach( (element) => {
          if (element.published) {
            this.marker = new CustomPinMarker([element.latitude!, element.longitude!], element.gppd_idnr).on('click', this.onPinClick).addTo(this.map);
                       
          }          
      });
    })
  }

  onPinClick() : void{
       console.log("In pinclick method");
       let observableVar! : Observable<PowerPlant>;
       let powerPlant! : PowerPlant;
       observableVar = this.powerPlantService.findByGPPD_INDR(this.marker.getId());

       observableVar.subscribe(data => {powerPlant = data});
       this.marker.bindPopup(""+ powerPlant.powerPlant_name + '<br\>' + powerPlant.country_name + '<br\>' + powerPlant.est_generation_gwh_2017
      + '<br\>' + powerPlant.primaryFuel ).openPopup();
  }
}

export class CustomPinMarker extends L.Marker {
   gppd_idnr: String | undefined;

  constructor(latLng: L.LatLngExpression, gppd_idnr: string | String | undefined, options?: L.MarkerOptions) {
    super(latLng, options);
    this.gppd_idnr = gppd_idnr;
  }

  getId() : any{
    return this.gppd_idnr;
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be, that `this` is not what you expect it to be when the code is exectuted at runtime. Check with `console.log(this)` inside the `onPinClick()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct answer after some modifications:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import { PowerPlantService } from 'src/app/services/power-plant.service';
import { PowerPlant } from 'src/app/models/power-plant.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
 //coordinates for Brasov
  private latitude: number = 45.6427;
  private longitude: number = 25.5887;
   
  private map!: L.Map;
  private centroid: L.LatLngExpression = [this.latitude, this.longitude];
  powerPlantList!: PowerPlant[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initMap();
  }
  
  constructor(private powerPlantService: PowerPlantService) {  }

  private initMap(): void {
    this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: this.centroid,
      zoom: 2.8
    });

    const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
    {
      minZoom: 2.8,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    });

    tiles.addTo(this.map);
  
    // this queries the database and retrieves a list of all the elements
    this.powerPlantService.getAll().subscribe(powerPlantArrayFromGet => {
      console.log(powerPlantArrayFromGet);
      this.powerPlantList = powerPlantArrayFromGet;
   // this loops through the list and creates and places a pin on the map at the location of each element
      this.powerPlantList.forEach( (element) => {
          if (element.published) {
            const that = this;
            //console.log(element.gppd_idnr + " 1")  ;  
            // this create the pin to be placed on the map and attaches to it a pop-up that, when clicked, will retrieve from the database information about that item and display it on the pop-up      
            let marker = new L.Marker([element.latitude!, element.longitude!])
              .on('click', function() {
                let observableVar! : Observable<PowerPlant>;
                let powerPlant! : PowerPlant;
                //console.log(element.gppd_idnr + " 2");
                observableVar = that.powerPlantService.findByGPPD_INDR(element.gppd_idnr + "");
            // the is where the interogation is done (above) and the pop-up is populated with the relevant information
                observableVar.subscribe(
                  data => 
                  {
                    powerPlant = data
            
                    var latlong : L.LatLng = new L.LatLng(<number> powerPlant.latitude, <number> powerPlant.longitude);

                    marker.setLatLng(latlong).bindPopup( 
                      powerPlant.powerPlant_name + 
                      '<br\>' + 
                      powerPlant.country_name + 
                      '<br\>' + 
                      powerPlant.est_generation_gwh_2017 + 
                      '<br\>' + 
                      powerPlant.primaryFuel )
                      .openPopup();
                  })
              })
              .addTo(that.map);                       
          }          
      });
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, the problem lies with misunderstanding what **this** means within your click handler. When using

```
this.marker = new CustomPinMarker([element.latitude!, element.longitude!], element.gppd_idnr)
  .on('click', this.onPinClick)
  .addTo(this.map);
```

You are passing the content of your function `onPinClick` to your event handler. Within your event handler **this** is the element that triggered the event. So it is the CustomPinMarker DOM object.

You can however circumvent this by wrapping your function in an arrow function to pass it to your event handler.

```
this.marker = new CustomPinMarker([element.latitude!, element.longitude!], element.gppd_idnr)
  .on('click', () => {
      this.onPinClick();
  })
  .addTo(this.map);
```

That works because arrow functions do not have their own `this` binding. These functions are resolved in the scope where they are declared in. In your case the HomeComponent.

Keep in mind, that by doing so you obviously lose the ability to access the triggering element. In case you need the element you could alias your HomeComponent and use that within an anonymous function in your event handler:

```
// that = HomeComponent, this = triggering DOM element
const that = this;
this.marker = new CustomPinMarker([element.latitude!, element.longitude!], element.gppd_idnr)
  .on('click', function() {
     let observableVar! : Observable<PowerPlant>;
     let powerPlant! : PowerPlant;
     observableVar = that.powerPlantService.findByGPPD_INDR(that.marker.getId());

   observableVar.subscribe(data => {powerPlant = data});
   that.marker.bindPopup(""+ powerPlant.powerPlant_name + '<br\>' + powerPlant.country_name + '<br\>' + powerPlant.est_generation_gwh_2017
  + '<br\>' + powerPlant.primaryFuel ).openPopup();
  })
  .addTo(that.map);
```

Comment: I have added your modifications and commented out the onPinClick() declaration that was created below and now the browser throws another similar error, but this time for powerPlant variable declared in the function().

"ERROR TypeError: powerPlant is undefined"

Comment: You seem to assign the value of `powerPlant` in an asynchronous `subscribe()` function, but using it's value in the synchronous `bindPopup`. Move everything from `that.marker.bindPopup [..]` until `openPopup` to the subscribe function.

Comment: Thank you, there is some progress. I still get an error but it's from the back end endpoint, I'm trying to figure it out.